# Corpus preprocessing

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, nltk

I am trying to preprocess a corpus to return a cleaned list of strings but i keep getting the error ' expected string or bytes like object'

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
nltk.download('punkt')
import time
import re
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
```

```
def load_sentences(file):
    """
    Reads a COHA sample file and pre-processes it into a list of strings.
    """
    sentences = []
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            sentences.append(line)          
    return sentences
```

```
corpus =  load_sentences('1800_sample.txt')
corpus
```

[result visualising data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkd4v.png)

```
def preprocessing(corpus):
    """
    Takes a collection of sentences and returns a cleaned version. 
    
    Complete this function by applying techniques like tokenisation, 
    non-word filtering, stop-word removal and stemming to clean the input.
    
    :return : a list of strings containing cleaned sentences
    :rtype : list(str)
    """
    clean_text = []
    # TODO: Pre-process corpus and add cleaned sentences to clean_text
        # word tokenisation
    # separate out words and strings of punctuation into separate white spaced words
    corpus = re.sub(r"(\w)([.,;:!?'\"”\)])", r"\1 \2", corpus)
    corpus = re.sub(r"([.,;:!?'\"“\(])(\w)", r"\1 \2", corpus)
    #print("tokenising:", text)
    # no other spelling normalization done for now
    tokens = re.split(r"\s+",corpus)
    tokens = clean_text   
    return clean_text
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBVuI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your preprocessing function sets clean_text to an empty list and then returns it. An empty list is not a 'string' or b'bytes-like-object'

You probably meant to have the line before somehow assign the tokens processing to clean_text. Just make sure you build your string back before you return it.